# An admin-friendly approach to establishing a permissions relationship between a file group and a user

Tags: files

The need is that when a new client project begins, that the client be given a username and password and have access to a specific piece of content that, in turn, gives access to download files, specific to that client, that were uploaded previously.

The ideal would be for the admin to have only these steps:

- Create the project content
- Create the project user
- Bulk upload the files

This is a nontechnical admin, so the need is to avoid granular steps for creating accounts or setting up folders, permissions, etc.

The concern for 1. is restricting access to the 'project'. I'm thinking that hooking content access and simply comparing the project name to the username (both would be the same).

The approach for 2. concerns linking the files uploaded with FileZilla to the content. It would be great if all files could be uploaded to the same folder, and then admin then do one selection to link several to the content/user. The less-desired approach would be uploading each project's files to a new folder.

I don't know if filefield_sources would created multiple instances of a file field so that each file would be listed when viewing the content, or whether it would need to be using something like IMCE to let the user browse, then download, from a folder that is linked to the username like the content access was.

Another thought is OG, but that might be overkill, and it's not ported yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The concern for 1** : you can use [Permissions by field](https://www.drupal.org/project/pbf)

> By adding fields of type Permissions by fields, you can manage access
>   to the node hosting these field by referencing other entity and
>   specifiy which access type you want to grant (none/standard
>   permission, view, update, delete) for users which reference same
>   entities (node, term, role or other users). You can also grant access
>   to the node directly per user if needed.

**The approach for 2** : (without using Fillezilla, but only backoffice) You can use [Plupload](https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload) to upload to upload files (pdf, jpeg...) massively through a content type
[image]
.After, you can link "file" content type to a project with a field entity reference in your content type "project". Add a "permission field" in your content type "file" to restrict access.
[image]

I dont know if I answer your question correctly